# How to prove by pumping lemma these languages are not regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language

1. $L_1 = (a^k * b^r \mid k \neq r^2)$
2. $L_2 = (a ^{\sum_i ^n t} \mid n > 0 )$

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I interpreted "(a ^(sigma from i to n) t | n > 0 )" correctly. Please switch it if I'm wrong. For one thing, the $t$ seems strange.

Comment: Are you sure that $i$ in the definition of $L_2$ isn't supposed to be $1$?  It would make more sense, since if $i > 1$, we'd need to pick some meaningful definition for $\sum_{t=i}^n$ when $n < i$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $L_1$ is regular. Let $n$ be a constant from pumping lemma (it depends only on language!). Consider word $w=a^{n!}b^{n!}$ which is clearly in $L_1$. By pumping lemma there exists words $w_1$, $w_2$ and $w_3$ such that $w=w_1w_2w_3$, $|w_2|>0$, $|w_1w_2|\leq n$ and $\forall_{i\in\mathbb{N}}w_1w_2^iw_3\in L_1$. So $w_2=a^l$ for some $l\in\mathbb{N}$ (because first $n$ letters of $w$ are all $a$s). But then it is easy to see that we can choose $i$ such that $w_1w_2^iw_3 = a^{(n!)^2}b^{n!} \notin L_1$

Now use a similar argument to prove that $L_2$ is not regular

EDIT: How does pumping lemma works? It says that if language $L$ is regular then there exists magic constant $n$ such that we can split every word $w\in L$ longer than $n$, into three parts $w_1w_2w_3$ (with $|w_1w_2|\ge n$) and "pump" the middle term as much as we want always obtaining a word from $L$. So in order to prove that language is not regular all we have to do is to find a word which lacks this property.

For $L_1$ if we take $w=a^{n!}b^{n!}$ and split it into $w_1w_2w_3$, there must be $w_1=a^k$, $w_2=a^l$ and $w_3=a^{n!-k-l}b^{n!}$ (not just $b^{n!}$ as you posted in your comment) with $k+l\le n$. So how does $w_1w_2^iw_3$ look like? It's $$a^ka^{li}a^{n!-k-l}b^{n!}=a^{n!+(i-1)l}b^{n!}$$Can we find $i$ such that $a^{n!+(i-1)l}b^{n!}\notin L_1$? Yes, thanks to factorial. We have $l\le n$, so both $(n!)^2$ and $n!$ are divisible by $l$. We only need to solve equation $n!+(i-1)l=(n!)^2$ which gives us $$i=\frac{(n!)^2-n!}{l}+1$$ and it is indeed a natural number. This contradicts pumping lemma and shows that $L_1$ is not regular.

Different (simpler) approach:
We can use a fact that language $L$ is regular iff it's complement $\bar{L}$ is regular. So it's sufficient to show that $\bar{L_1}=(a^kb^r|k=r^2)$ is not regular. So assume that $\bar{L_1}$ is regular and let $n$ be a constant from pumping lemma. Now looking at word $w=a^{n^2}b^n$ we see that if we split it into $w=w_1w_2w_3$ with $|w_1w_2|\le n$ then $w_2=a^k$ for some $k>0$ and $w_1w_2^2w_3=a^{n^2+k}b^n$ which is not in $\bar{L_1}$ because $n^2+k \neq n^2$

Comment: thanks but if you can change your answer becuase its : k  != r^2 , not k!  =  r^2    ( k is not r * r)

Comment: Yes, k is not equal r square :) That's the question I answered

Comment: I dont really understand, which i can i choose ? if i take w1 = a^s , w2 = a^t , t > 0 , s>= 0 , s + t <= n , and w3 =b^n! w1w2w3 = a^s* a^t * a ^ n! - s - t * b ^ n! whats next?

Comment: why is $w_1w^i_2w_3 = a^{(n!)^2}b^{n!}$ ???

Comment: @user14988 there was a little mistake I have corrected. And I also included different solution. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that the assignment asked you to use the pumping lemma, but I always like to solve these kinds of problems using the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) directly, both because it's often easier and more informative than just blindly applying the pumping lemma without understanding what's really going on, and also because, frankly, I can never remember the exact statement of the [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) off the top of my head, whereas the pigeonhole principle is so simple and obvious that one *can't* really forget it.  Besides, it can often do the job [even in cases where the pumping lemma fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57349/is-the-language-of-all-strings-over-the-alphabet-a-b-c-with-the-same-number-of).

The basic idea is that a language $L$ is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) if and only if it is the language accepted by some [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).  Let that DFA have $n$ states.  Informally, what we want to show is that an $n$-state DFA can only count up to $n$.  Thus, if we can demonstrate that correctly accepting (only) the language $L$ would require distinguishing more than $n$ states, for *any* given $n$, then we've shown that $L$ cannot be regular.

For example, let's start with $L_1 = \{a^k b^r \mid k \ne r^2\}$.  If this language were accepted by an $n$-state DFA, then by the pigeonhole principle, there would have to be two distinct numbers $i$ and $j$, with $0 \le i < j \le n$, such that the DFA would be in the same state after reading the strings $a^i$ and $a^j$.
Now, let $r \ge \sqrt{i}$ and let $k = r^2$, so that $m = k - i \ge 0$.  To reject any input not in $L_1$, the DFA must, in particular, reject the input $a^k b^r = a^i a^m b^r$.  But this means that it must also reject the input $a^j a^m b^r$ which *does* belong to $L_1$, which means that $L_1$ cannot be the language it accepts.  Since this holds for *any* DFA with *any* finite number of states, it follows that $L_1$ cannot be a regular language.

As for $L_2 = \{ a^{\sum_{t=1}^n t} \mid n > 0 \} = \{ a^1 a^2 \dots a^n \mid n > 0 \}$ (where I'm assuming you meant $1$ instead of $i$ for the reasons stated in my comment above), let $m$ be the number of states in the DFA supposedly accepting $L_2$ (since the variable $n$ is already in use) and consider the set of input prefixes $p_k = a^1 a^2 \dots a^{m-1} a^k$ for $0 \le k \le m$.  There are $m+1$ such prefixes, so there must be two of them, $p_i$ and $p_j$ with $i < j$, such that the DFA ends up in the same state after reading each of them.  But this means that, in order to accept the input $p_i a^{m-i} \in L_2$, it must also accept $p_j a^{m-i} \notin L_2$.

Comment: In my opinion it's really hard to forget exact statement of the pumping lemma if you really know what's going on there. It's just saying that if we look at DFA (with $n$ states) for regular language $L$ as on a directed graph of states of this DFA, then every word longer than $n$ needs to make a loop in this graph within first $n+1$ characters, and we can repeat that loop as long as we want to. So in $w=w_1w_2w_3$ the $w_2$ term corresponds to that loop.